# Compiz uses lots of CPU and memory on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, 16.04, compiz, ccsm

According to System Monitor, at any given time, compiz is using 25-50% CPU and that is really problematic on my slow computer. I have already tried to reset settings to default, disabled the Sync to VBlank, and changed the texture filter to Fast in CCSM. Unfortunately, none of these have helped. Any other solutions?

Comment: "Compiz" and "slow computer" don't go well together. Please post the specs.